# Google cloud automatically delete the last service account key created

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, key

As part of an automation, I am trying to create a temporary access key for the service account, do changes and then delete this last used key.

Where I am stuck is listing and doing something with this result:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys list --iam-account=dummy@dummy.com --format=json
```

This command will list randomly all the available keys for this service account and I haven't found a good formatting to help me.

Tried using the date value ( year-month-day ) with and without a wildcard *, but it doesn't recognise it.

```
> gcloud iam service-accounts keys list --iam-account=dummy@dummy.com
> --format="value(validAfterTime[2021-07-11])"
```

Logically I would want to probably compare the values inside validAfterTime for each of the keys and then get the highest one, but I do not know how to do that programatically in shell.
In python I would compare the values and get the name of the one with the biggest value.

What would be a good simple way to get the last one created so I can delete it?

### EDIT

Ok, so it was simpler than I thought. What I needed to do is to also add the flag sort-by and there I will put the same validAfterTime.

```
> gcloud iam service-accounts keys list --iam-account=dummy@dummy.com
> --format="value(validAfterTime[2021-07-11])" --sort-by=validAfterTime | tail -1 | awk -F/ '{print $6}'
```

Sort by will sort in ascending order the values, tail -1 will give me the last result, print 6 will give me the 6th element using / as a delimiter.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The command you should be using looks like this:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys list --iam-account=dummy@dummy.com
--format=json --sort-by=~validAfterTime --limit=1
```

Based on [Google Cloud SDK Reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/keys/list#--limit) the --sort-by do:

> Comma-separated list of resource field key names to sort by. The
> default order is ascending. Prefix a field with ``~´´ for descending
> order on that field

So you can use `sort-by` to get the last entry on the SA Keys based on `validAfterTime` field. And you can use --limit to limit the number of entries you will get.

Comment: Thank you, but be careful because limit will give you the first result, not the last. So if you want the last key as I requested you will need to tail -1 or something equivalent. Is there a different way to do the limit from gcloud for the last result?